# To insert scala code for two methods

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors

Consider the LL1 grammer:
      ::=  |  | num
      ::= +  
     ::= *

Now consider the set of scala cases classes. Below code is given and I only need to add code inside the expr() and times() method

```
sealed abstract class Token
case object PlusToken extends Token
case object TimesToken extends Token
case class NumToken(value:Int) extends Token

def isExpr(tokens:List[Token]):Boolean = {    
var remaining = tokens
   object ParseError extends Exception

   def expr():Unit = // ** add code here

   def plus():Unit = {
     if (remaining.headOption != Some(PlusToken)) throw ParseError
     remaining = remaining.tail
     expr()
     expr()
   }

   def times():Unit = // ** add code here

 try {
 expr()
 if (remaining.isEmpty)
    true
 else
    false
} catch {
 case ParseError => false
 }
}
```

I need to add code for the expr() and times() method in such a way that isExpr() returns whether the list of tokens passed to it can be derived from  according to the grammar.

Output should be in following ways:

```
isExpr(List(PlusToken, NumToken(5), NumToken(3)))               => true
isExpr(List(PlusToken, PlusToken))                              => false
isExpr(List(PlusToken, NumToken(1)))                            => false
isExpr(List(PlusToken, NumToken(9), NumToken(8), NumToken(7)))  => false
```

Following is my code for expr() and times() method:

```
sealed abstract class Token
case object PlusToken extends Token
case object TimesToken extends Token
case class NumToken(value:Int) extends Token

def isExpr(tokens:List[Token]):Boolean = 
{
 var remaining = tokens
 object ParseError extends Exception

 def expr():Unit = // ** add code here
 {
     if(remaining.HeadOption == Some(PlusToken))
       plus()
       else if(remaining.headOption == Some(TimesToken))
       times()
     else remaining = remaining.tail
 }

   def plus():Unit = 
   {
     if (remaining.headOption != Some(PlusToken)) throw ParseError
     remaining = remaining.tail
     expr()
     expr()
   } 

   def times():Unit = // ** add code here
   {
     if (remaining.headOption != Some(TimesToken)) throw ParseError
     remaining = remaining.tail
     expr()
     expr()
   }
   try 
   {
     expr()
     if (remaining.isEmpty)
       true
     else
    false
   } catch 
   {
     case ParseError => false
   }
def main(argv: Array[String]) {}
}
```

For my code, I am getting compile time error. Error is: excepted class or object definition. 
Also, I am not sure how to use the main class to print whatever is expected. Please look into my scala code as I am completely new to it and provide your input.

Comment: Consider the LL1 Grammer:                                                                  <expr>  ::= <plus> | <times> | num
<plus>  ::= + <expr> <expr>
<times> ::= * <expr> <expr> and the error is coming on                       def isExpr(tokens:List[Token]):Boolean =

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your code outside of an object (`class`, `trait`, or `object`) as the error is stating. So you need to wrap the code inside of one of those structures.

Example for object

```
object Main {
  def someMethod....
  def main(argv: Array[String]) {
    ...main entry point of your system...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not getting any error now. But my next question was how do I write the main function to get the desired output.

Comment: Just println it in the main? Im not sure if you are looking for more than that?